# one of the following is acceptable for updateable view

Tags: sql

one of the following is acceptable for updateable view

options are:

```
a. aggregate function
b. where
c. join
d. group by
```

which option is correct?

Comment: Oracle or mysql?

Comment: tell me for both

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: I'd say all of them. (If you have them in the WHERE clause.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is Oracle, then **c** because

- **a** and **d** return "ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view"
- **b** returns "ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"

---

Example for **a** and **d**:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp as
  2  select deptno, sum(sal) sumsal from emp
  3  group by deptno;

View created.

SQL> update v_emp set deptno = 30;
update v_emp set deptno = 30
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
```

Example for **b**:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp as
  2  select d.deptno, e.ename, e.sal
  3  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;

View created.

SQL> update v_emp set sal = 1000;
update v_emp set sal = 1000
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

Example for **c**:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp as
  2  select * From emp
  3  where deptno = 10;

View created.

SQL> update v_emp set sal = 1000;

3 rows updated.

SQL>
```

Comment: if MySQL then which option?

Comment: I presume the same, but I don't use MySQL so I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Your B also includes C.